# How can I install rosbag2 plugin in ros2 foxy

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, ros2, rosbag

I am trying to install ros2bag plugin, while doing this I am encountering with this error.

```
Starting >>> ros1_rosbag_storage_vendor
Finished <<< ros1_rosbag_storage_vendor [1.05s]                  
Starting >>> rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins
--- stderr: rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (message):
  Failed to find ROS 1 roscpp, cannot build.


---
Failed   <<< rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins [0.74s, exited with code 1]
                                
Summary: 1 package finished [2.02s]
  1 package failed: rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins
  1 package had stderr output: rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins

Can someone please help me.
```

I tried using git clone and then colcon build

Answer (score 0):

You need to [install ROS 1](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation).

It looks like `rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins` is [looking for its dependency `roscpp`](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2_bag_v2/blob/master/rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins/CMakeLists.txt#L28)

This means that you don't have ROS 1 (properly) installed. As is mentioned is a requirement [here](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2_bag_v2#requirements).

If you install `rosbag2_bag_v2_plugins` from the bloomed debian package like `ros-humble-rosbag2-bag-v2-plugins` (on Ubuntu), it will automatically install what you need from `ros-noetic-*`. But since you are doing it from source, and since `rosdep` can't help you, you need to install ROS 1 manually as as a separate step.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I already have ros1 Noetic installed also roscpp is available as a dependency in my system.

Comment: But, I will have a look at it by installing it again.

Comment: Did you source ROS 1? https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2_bag_v2#building-the-ros-1-plugin